# Calling older .NET Framework DbContext class library application within a .NET 5 console application?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-5

I am writing a simple console application in .NET Core 5 and would like to use an existing datalayer and services, these have been written in .NET Framework 4.7.

My approach so far is something like this:

```
class Program
{
    private static IConfigurationRoot _configuration;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetParent(AppContext.BaseDirectory).FullName)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
            .Build();


        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(_configuration)
            .AddSingleton<MyApp.DataLayer.Interfaces.IExample, MyApp.DataLayer.Concrete.Example>()
            .AddSingleton<MyApp.Models.Interfaces.IExample2, MyApp.Models.Coordinators.Example2>()
            .AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")))
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        var data = serviceProvider.GetService<IExample>().GetData();
        // do a bunch of stuff here involving services passed into the ServiceCollection() call
}
```

`appsettings.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "ConnectionStrings": 
    {
        "MyConnectionString": "Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    }
}
```

The error I hit is: `No connection string named 'MyConnectionString' could be found in the application config file.` This error happens when reaching this peice of code in the data layer:  `public MyAppContext() : base("name=MyConnectionString") {}`

Comment: Where did you define `_connectionString`?

Comment: sorry, my bad pasting / simplification of code. edited.

Comment: .NETt 5 is .NET *Core* 5. It can't use any .NET Old libraries. The library should be modified to target .NET Standard at least, and use an EF version that targets .NET Core or .NET Standard, like EF 6.4.4 or all EF Core versions

Comment: If your DbContext is old .Net 4.7 then it expects your connection strings to be in app.config or web.config  not in appSettings.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constructor for a class that extends `DbContext` would use a constructor that looks something like this:

```
public DbEntities(IConfiguration _configuration) :
    base(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbEntities>()
        .UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString"))
        .Options)
{ }
```

Note: If you are using Entity Framework Core, you should create a separate `DbEntities` file that will contain all of the Entity Framework properties and methods.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample of using [EF 6 in .NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/data/entity-framework-6/3.xsample/MVCCore/Startup.cs).

You can't use `.AddDbContext` for a EF6 DbContext, and the EF6 DbContext no-arg constructor that access the .NET Framework configuration system doesn't work.

So this:

```
.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")))
```

should be

```
 .AddScoped<MyContext>(_ => new MyContext(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString")));
```